# What is mean by application must run out of /opt?

Tags: application-development

when I was going to rules of Ubuntu Apps Showdown, I found this rule:

- **Application must run out of /opt.**

What is means by this?
Checkout Rules:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In general**, apps running from `/opt` are self-contained, i.e. they don't spread their footprint far and wide into `/bin`, `/lib`, `/usr`, etc. like *normal* APT-installed packages do. Basically, your app should stick to `/opt` except for any user data in `/home/user` as @konrad suggested.

Answer (score 3):

All applications submitted through the Application Review Board (ARB) process (which I assume the app showdown is utilizing - although it does not say explicitly) must install and run from /opt/. The application can save data into a sane place in the home directory preferably following freedesktop.org suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If you run `quickly submitubuntu`, it'll create a package where everything runs from the `/opt` directory. Or at least, that's the answer I got [when I asked this question](http://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntuappshowdown/comments/vmgh7/question_quickly_contest_rules/).